# While loop slows down as time passes on Python

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, while-loop

I'm trying to scrape some data from a website that detects live fotball odds drop and if there is a specific change in the HTML of the page,it will send me a notification to a Telegram bot that I've made..here is my code:

```
from distutils.command.clean import clean
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

ids_list=[]
game_urls=[] 
game_name=[]
gfix=[]
livecapper_url ="https://livecapper.ru/bet365/" #the website link

while(True):
    page=requests.get(livecapper_url,verify=False).text
    soup = bs(page , "html.parser")
    game_ids = soup.find_all(game_id=True) #getting the IDs of every football game
    for g in game_ids:
            x=g.get('game_id')
            ids_list.append(x)   #putting the IDs on a list

    for id in ids_list:
            game_url = f"https://livecapper.ru/bet365/event.php?id={id}" #the URL of every single football game
            game_urls.append(game_url)

    for g in game_urls:
            response=requests.get(g).text
            soup = bs(response, "html.parser")
            for t in soup.find_all("td",class_=['red1','red2','red3'], limit=1): #detecting the change in HTML
                for g in soup.find_all("h1"):
                    game_name.append(g.get_text()) if g.get_text() not in game_name else game_name

    for f in game_name:
            game_url= 'https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=-609XXXXXX&text=Fixed Alert : {}'.format(f) #sending notification to telegram bot
            if game_url not in gfix:
                gfix.append(game_url)
                requests.get(game_url)
            else:
                pass       

    ids_list.clear
    game_name.clear
    game_urls.clear
    time.sleep(1)
```

As you can see I'm using the `While (True):` method to run the code 24/7 but the problem is that each iteration lasts twice as long as the previous one approximately .

e.g.
1st iteration=10s | 2nd iteration=20s | 3rd iteration=40s | 4th iteration=80s

What can I do to make all the iterations work as fast as possible?

Comment: aren't you looping through more game_names and game_urls with each iteration of the while loop?

Comment: Note that your calls to `clear` at the end aren't doing anything because you aren't calling the methods. You need `.clear()`. Also, not the problem, but the `game_name.append(g.get_text()) if g.get_text() . . .` line is suspicious. `else game_name` doesn't make sense there since the results aren't being used. Did you mean for the conditional expression to be inside the call to `append`?

Comment: I also think you can achieve what you're attempting with a single second-level loop, not 4

Comment: @Carcigenicate This line checks if the element is in the list..If yes: nothing happens that's why I've put `else game_name` so the list will remain the same. But if the element is not in the list..It has to be appended.

Comment: @Joksova Then you should have just written ` if g.get_text(): game_name.append(g.get_text())`. It doesn't make sense to have a conditional expression default to a dummy value instead of just using a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a few issues with the code, but ultimately the reason it takes longer each time is you continue to append to your lists, so  after each iteration that list will grow bigger and bigger (included with duplicates). There's a few things you could do:

1. Put those initial empty list within your loop
2. remove duplicates from the list so it's not requesting the same thing multiple times in each iteration
3. Correctly use `.clear()`

I simply did 1, since what it looks like you want is to start each iteration with a clear list.

```
from distutils.command.clean import clean
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


gfix=[]
livecapper_url ="https://livecapper.ru/bet365/" #the website link

while(True):
    ids_list=[]
    game_urls=[] 
    game_name=[]
    page=requests.get(livecapper_url,verify=False).text
    soup = bs(page , "html.parser")
    game_ids = soup.find_all(game_id=True) #getting the IDs of every football game
    for g in game_ids:
            x=g.get('game_id')
            ids_list.append(x)   #putting the IDs on a list

    for id in ids_list:
            game_url = f"https://livecapper.ru/bet365/event.php?id={id}" #the URL of every single football game
            game_urls.append(game_url)

    for g in game_urls:
            response=requests.get(g).text
            soup = bs(response, "html.parser")
            for t in soup.find_all("td",class_=['red1','red2','red3'], limit=1): #detecting the change in HTML
                for g in soup.find_all("h1"):
                    game_name.append(g.get_text()) if g.get_text() not in game_name else game_name

    for f in game_name:
            game_url= 'https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=-609XXXXXX&text=Fixed Alert : {}'.format(f) #sending notification to telegram bot
            if game_url not in gfix:
                gfix.append(game_url)
                requests.get(game_url)
            else:
                pass       

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change these:

```
    ids_list.clear
    game_name.clear
    game_urls.clear
```

to:

```
    ids_list.clear()
    game_name.clear()
    game_urls.clear()
```

Without the parentheses, you aren't calling the methods, but are merely accessing them and then discarding them (i.e., it does nothing).

Comment: they do _something_, they _technically_ slow down their code

Comment: thank you..that really decreased the time but putting initial empty list within the loop helped me more.